# Sending IoT data to Azure

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a device which can be configured to send some environmental data (temperature, humidity, air pressure, luminosity, ...). The supported methods for the device gateway are MQTT, UDP, WebHook and the data format can be CSV or Json.

Assume that there are 30 (or more) devices in a building and they will send the data every second to the Azure cloud. Then, I want to do some analytics on the cloud.

I want to know which method has the best performance?

I have tried Azure Functions using WebHook: it charges for every request.

But, I think the best one may be Azure IoT Hub sending MQTT data.

Comment: If sending the data to IoT Hub, be sure to check out Stream Analytics also. Using that you can do some aggregation, push data to some kind of repository and trigger your functions on this repository. That way the you won't have 30 functions running each second of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use azure function EventHub Trigger with connection string to Azure IoT hub:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs

https://www.10thmagnitude.com/tech-blog/step-step-guide-creating-functions-within-azures-iot-hub/

Comment: Why not to send data to Azure IoT Hub directly? Which one is better? Azure Functions just supports standard HTTP and WebHook. How about using UDP or MQTT? Sorry, I am asking too many questions! :)

Comment: To add to Alexey's point, your devices should send data to Azure IoT Hub.  Then you create EventHub-Triggered Azure Functions to retrieve and process those events from your Azure IoT Hub.  We are referring to EventHub-Triggered Functions because Azure Functions currently do not yet have support for IoT Hub triggers, so you need to get the EventHub compatible connection string from your IoT Hub and use it to setup your EventHub-Triggered Function.